# How can I calculate my win rate on one column based on the date on another?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I created a rudimentary Google Form to track my win rate at Starcraft. The first column on the resulting Google Sheet is Timestamp created by the form.

I have another column that has my win-loss, and I am able to calculate my percentage for the entire sheet (all games). However, I want to be able to see my daily win rate, and I can't figure out the correct way to go about it.

I tried COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, with TODAY() and I was able to count the games for a certain day, but I don't know how to use it to tie in with my win-loss column. What I currently do is adjust my Daily formula to specify today's date before playing. I was hoping I won't need to do this.

Please see [Win-Loss Stats Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AWplrSITvUUxcYkwXJAWlfnI4O8vOHBJk_8l_s7Hn2k/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can extend your formula to compare against the date in column A:

```
=(COUNTIFS(D2:D, "Win", ARRAYFORMULA(INT(A2:A)),TODAY())/((COUNTIFS(D2:D, "Win",ARRAYFORMULA(INT(A2:A)),TODAY()))+(COUNTIFS(D2:D, "Loss",ARRAYFORMULA(INT(A2:A)),TODAY()))))
```

The additional condition would be `ARRAYFORMULA(INT(A2:A)),TODAY()`, which converts the timestamps into dates and compares them to today's date.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize the first column was not in date format. Thank you for the breakdown. It really helps me wrap my head around on what is happening. THANK YOU!